# Ошибка при клике помогите

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
window.onload = function() {
  'use strict'
  var painting;
  var context;
  var x, i, j;
  var y;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.lineWidth = 9;
  context.strokeRect(420, 200, 400, 200);

  canvas.onmousedown = startDraw;
  canvas.onmouseup = draw;
  socket.on( 'startDraw', function( data ) {
  startDraw( data.x, data.y );
});

function startDraw(e) {
    'use strict'
    painting = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
}
socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } );


function draw(r) {
    'use strict'
    i = r.pageX;
    j = r.pageY;
    if ( painting == true ) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( x, y );
        context.lineTo( i, j );
        context.stroke();
    }
}

function stopDraw() {
    'use strict'
    painting = false;
}
```

}

Ошибка

> Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined

Comment: вы передает объект с ключами x и y, а внутри тела обработчика пытаетесь обратиться к ключу pageX и pageY.
e.x и e.y вам нужно использовать.

Comment: @dakiesse, неправда же. От этого такой ошибки быть не может.

Comment: сделайте console.log(e) и вы все сами увидете, а так же вывод суда выложите

Comment: MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 565, screenY: 330, clientX: 500, clientY: 221…}

Comment: а где у вас подписчик на событие startDraw? socket.on('startDraw', func)

Comment: socket.on( 'startDraw', function( data ) {
        startDraw( data.x, data.y );
    });
 
    function startDraw(e) {
        'use strict'
        painting = true;
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        console.log(e);
    }
    socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } );

Comment: добавь код в вопрос свой

Comment: внутри обработчика ты вызываешь startDraw и передаешь два аргумента. я не совсем понимаю как у тебя аргумент e в startDraw является MouseEvent, учитывая что ты вызывая эту функцию передаешь в нее два аргумента и первый это data.x

Comment: @dakiesse - он, очевидно, вызвал console.log не там где Вы имели в виду. Напишите ответ.

Comment: @Igor а еще предполагаю, что функция startDraw не только вызывает в обработчике события startDraw, но и весит на событие мыши

Comment: @RomanPawliw полный листинг кода нужен

Comment: @RomanPawliw как я и предполагал, у вас функция startDraw являет обработчиком двух событий и если она обрабатывает событие mousedown, то в нее передается MouseEvent, а в случаи события startDraw функция startDraw вызывается с data.x и data.y которые впринцепи изначально undefined. У вас проблема в потоке выполнения. Вы во время объявления все этого дела зачем то эмитте событие startDraw и передаете туда undefined аргументы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в самом начале объявляет переменные `x` и `y`, которые имею тип данных `undefined`.

Далее вы вешаете на `canvas.onmousedown` обработчик функцию `startDraw`. И при клике по `canvas` у вас естетственно произойдет вызов функции `starDraw` с арументов `MouseEvent`.

Далее, во время выполнения потока вы просто так эмиттете событие `startDraw` посредством вызова `socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } );`. Какова цель данного вызова и передача в нее хэша с значениями `{x: undefined, y: undefined}`? Так как я не понимаю вашу задумку, я просто вам указываю, что проблема именно в этой строке.

**UPDATE** после нормального отображения листинга:

У вас получается в потоке выполнения происходит вызов `socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } );` с переменными `x` и `y`, которые вообще не были иниацилизованы. `window.unload` выполниться позже чем произойдет выполнение `socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } );`!

Comment: Надо сделать в реалтайме рисовалку

Comment: @RomanPawliw у вас слишком много ошибок. По потому, что я вижу вы не понимаете, что такое области видимости (scopes). Вы объявили переменные, которые используется везде в приватном scope, а именно в обработчике onload. Вынесите переменные x, y, painting и т.д. наружу.

Comment: @RomanPawliw далее у вас бессмысленно использование use strick. Зачем оно? Конечно оно в данном случаи роль не играет, но это лишнее!

Comment: @RomanPawliw далее, вызов socket.emit( 'startDraw', { x: x, y: y } ); вы наверное все таки хотели помести внутрь функции startDraw и тем самым оповещать другие клиентов о том, что ВЫ рисуете на холсте

Comment: @RomanPawliw далее, вы так же подписываетесь на событие startDraw и получается, что вы же и эмиттет это событие с передачей координ и тут же случаете и обрабатываете это событие и хотите то, что вы уже прорисовали - еще раз прорисовать. Проблема с логикой поведения приложения. К тому же обработчик события 'startDraw' не верно написан. Вы должны вызывать функцию draw внутри и передавать туда объект с x и y